# Center is origin for linearized system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, linearization

I have the following system

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
\dot{x} & {}={} 1 + x^2y - 3x = f(x,y) \\
\dot{y} & {}={}2x - yx^2 = g(x,y)
  \end{aligned} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

with one equilibrium point $A(1,2)$. After linearizing around $A$, I obtain the system

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
\dot{x} & = x + y \\
\dot{y} & = -2x - y
  \end{aligned} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

The eigenvalues of the matrix $J$ of system (2) are $λ_{1,2} = \pm \mathrm{i}$. Because the origin is center for system (2) we can't apply Hartman-Grobamn Theorem. But can I do this instead?

Let us consider $F=(f,g)$. Then $\mathrm{div}F = 2xy - 3 - x^2 < 0$ around $A(1,2)$ if we consider a region $S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{2} \ \mathrm{and} \ \frac{3}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{5}{2} \}$. Then, the equilibrium point $A$ will be an attractor. Thus, $A$ is asympotically stable focus. Is this right or wrong? Do we know that if the origin is center for the linearized system then the equilibrium point for the nonlinear system will be either a center or a focus?

Thanks for any help / guidance.

Comment: Please add some steps for the divergence, the trace of a traceless matrix should be zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, the trace is zero. The eigenvalues are $\pm \mathrm{i}$. Also, $\mathrm{div}F = f_x + g_y = 2xy - 3 - 2xy = -3$. What I ask is if I can derive that $A(1,2)$ will be an asympotically stable focus.

Comment: That is wrong, $g_y=-x^2$. The divergence is the trace of the Jacobian, and the Jacobian at the fixed point is the system matrix of the linearization.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes you are right. I corrected the divergence. But around $A$ isn't the divergence negative? For example at the region $S$ that I descride above? So, if divergence is negative around an equilibrium point then that point will be an attrcator.

Comment: If you can prove that, yes. But the expression does not look to me like it would have a maximum in $A$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Which expression? Yes, I have ploted the phase portrait. That is how I know that $A$ is a focus. I showed that $\mathrm{div} F$ is negative around $A$. So can I conclude that $A$ will be an asympotically stable focus?

Comment: The expression for the divergence (after correction). ${\rm div} F=-(x-1)^2-2(x-1)-\not1+2(x-1)(y-2)+4(x-1)+2(y-2)+\not4-\not3$ has directions where it is positive, as for points close to $A$ the linear terms dominate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142035/discussion-between-legendcero-and-lutz-lehmann).

Comment: @LutzLehmann I moved the discussion in chat, as this was a propostition by the site.